# How to stop button moving at the desired position (timer included)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form. With 1 button on the left side and 1 label on the right side.
I want button on click to move till it reach the label and then stop and go false. At the moment my button is only moving from right to left side , but it will stop only on the click. I need it to stop either on the click or when it reach the final point - label.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Left++;  
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;

        if (timer1.Enabled)
        {
            button1.Text = "Brauc!";
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Text = "Sakt braukt!";
            timer1.Stop();
        }             
    }
```

Comment: Check the button's position vs the label's position in the Tick event.  Stop the timer if it reaches or exceeds that position.

Answer (score 1):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a precise explanation of what the code does and (especially) what you want the code to do instead, it's impossible to know for sure what the best answer for you would be.

But based on the code you posted, I would expect something like the following should work:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Left++;

    int buttonMoveLimit = label1.Left - button1.Width;

    if (button1.Left >= buttonMoveLimit)
    {
        button1.Left = buttonMoveLimit;
        SetTimer(false);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetTimer(!timer1.Enabled);
}

private void SetTimer(bool enabled)
{
    timer1.Enabled = enabled;
    button1.Text = timer1.Enabled ? "Brauc!" : "Sakt braukt!";
}
```

**Note:** you do not need to both set `Enabled` and call `Start()` or `Stop()`. Setting the property value is equivalent to calling `Start()` or `Stop()` and vice a versa.